# Can android webview access the Android sqlite database content using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, webview

I have a SQLite DB(say, Employees is the DB name) cretaed by my android application. I also have a webview in my application. Is it possible i can access the DB Employees data inside the webview using the javascripts.

Please suggest me a sample where I can proceed to.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way is to use

> public void addJavascriptInterface (Object object, String name)

The javascript code in the webview will rely on the Android native code to do the SQLite commands

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WebSettings method [setDatabasePath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) and this answer – [android WebView HTML5 access database problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676871/android-webview-html5-access-database-problem).

Comment: I m able to create a DB inside a webview . My question is to access the Db which already exists as part of my Activity based sqlite DB created ,  How to access the same inside the webview using the javascripts. Any sample code if i could get would be of great help

Comment: @user874353: have you found a solution to this aspect. I'm in similar situation. My javascript code works with a different db in path, i would like it to work with the one from /data/data/databases/.. If you know, post a response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014163/android-query-the-apps-db-thru-javascript