# HTML5 on Android with access to SQLite database

Tags: java, android, html, sqlite, responsive-design

I have an app that is written in java and runs on Android 7. The app communicates with the backend and saves the data from backend into the local SQLite database. This stored data is used permanently and therefore the database is repeatedly searched for data via SQL and new data is also written in SQLite.  I plan to write one or more activities in HTML5.
The question: is there a way from HTML5 to access SQLite and instances of Java classes of the client?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676871/android-webview-html5-access-database-problem Doest this question help ?

Comment: Not directly but I found another question with usefull answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript. Thanks!